# How to override XMLHttpRequest in Firefox's WebExtension

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to override the **XMLHttpRequest.protype.open** method in Firefox's WebExtension. 
I have written a following code in content script

```
var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass) {
    console.log("url :"+url+"\n method: "+method);
    oldOpen.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

But this code is not working. If anyone know that how to override the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open method then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts making XHR requests have no access to the content script. Your content script has to insert a script with your code into the page. The inserted page script can communicate with the content script by messages.
For details inserting a script into a page see here:
[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script). For details communicating page script and content script see here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts (section "Communication with the embedding page")