# Webextension: How to transparently modify XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon-webextensions, interception

## My goal

… is to have a web extension (in Firefox for now) that intercepts and modified XMLHttpRequests issues by a site as transparently as possible. Best case is that the extension is undetectable by the site even when explicitly looking for it. For example, I want to be able to automatically redact/replace critical data before it is send out or enforce caching of large images despite the original page disabling that explicitly.

## Original approach

Use a background script and `browser.webRequest` with `blocking` to intercept all requests.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  modifySend,
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
  },
  ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);

browser.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  modifyReceive,
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
  },
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

This works to some degree. While I can **view** all requests, changing the content of sends (POST) is not possible and (some?) changed headers of received are ignored by Firefox. For example I was not able to overwrite `cache-control`, the original value was still effective.

## Content scripts

Since I'm only interested in XMLHttpRequests why not have a content script modify those [as suggested in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447335/13215250). Unfortunately, content scripts are [isolated from the page they run in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40868620/13215250) and injected scripts are detectable. The problem of changing response headers is also not solved.

## Questions

What is the proper way to intercept and modify XMLHttpRequests? Is it even possible to the degree I want? And as an extension: How to I provide large data blobs as a response, for example if I do my own caching when I cannot persuade the browser to ignore "no caching" headers?

Comment: You're almost there: modify XHR prototype in page context via [wrappedJSObject + exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts). As for cache-control header I don't think browsers allow extensions to change that.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used two separate approaches. One for providing large data blobs and one for `XMLHttpRequest` interception.

### Content blobs

The easiest option seems to provide the data as [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources) and then use the extension's background script to enforce redirects:

```
function serveLocally(details)
{
  const localRes = browser.runtime.getManifest().web_accessible_resources;
  let ret = {};

  localRes.forEach(file => {
    if (details.url.endsWith(file))
    {
      ret.redirectUrl = browser.runtime.getURL(file);
    }
  });
  return ret;
}
```

### Interception

Here I use a content script which [injects a script into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/13215250). The injected script [overwrites the `open` function of `XMLHttpRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26447335/13215250):

content.js

```
function injectJS(file) {

  let D = document;
  let s = D.createElement('script');

  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = browser.runtime.getURL(file);
  s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
  };

  (D.head || D.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}

injectJS("inject.js");
```

inject.js (separate file and among the `web_accessible_resources`)

```
let realOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  let method = arguments[0];
  let url = arguments[1];
  ...  
  realOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```