# Webextension: Set response headers for web_accessible_resources

Tags: redirect, firefox-addon-webextensions, response-headers

To provide some custom caching via a webextension, I use [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources) and redirect accesses towards them in a background script – see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61549859/13215250) for details.

While that works content wise, I cannot find a way to change the response headers of the cached content, for example the [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) header. So when I cache content that the original website does some consistence checks on, this will fail.

I tried to intercept the redirected response with an `onHeadersReceived` handler, but this never triggers as [“Only requests made using HTTP or HTTPS will trigger events”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/RequestFilter) and my redirect uses the `moz-extension://` protocol.

How does one set response headers when serving `web_accessible_resources`?
Is it possible at all?

Comment: Since Firefox is unable to intercept moz-extension:// scheme in webRequest even for extension's own URLs, I guess your only option is to register a service worker inside a content script (I don't know though how that would work on sites that already have one).

Comment: @wOxxOm Nice idea, didn't even consider service workers yet. I have to try if 1) they can be created by a content script and 2) what their scope is in that case (hopefully that of the extension). Likely, a worker needs to be combined with the existing method of a webRequest that does the redirect first. The worker would then only add the headers.